# VB.net ListBox get similar data from access database but when i click it only shows the last record

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, listbox

The program works good, but when it comes to similar data, the search finds them and list them to the ListBox but when I click to show them on a TextBox or RichTextBox, it only shows the last record of the database.

What I want is to get similar data from MS Access database and show them to a TextBox.
For more details, I have got the screenshot.
[image]

And the code is:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

Dim Con As OleDbConnection

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim sString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=system\default.mdb"
    Con = New OleDbConnection
    Con.ConnectionString = sString
    If Not Con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        Con.Open()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub dbLoad()
    If (TextBox1.Text = "") Then
        TextBox2.Text = ":)"
    Else
        Try
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select * from data where name like '" & TextBox1.Text & "' ", Con)
            Dim rdr As OleDbDataReader
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            If rdr.HasRows Then
                While rdr.Read
                    TextBox2.Text = CStr(rdr("info"))
                End While
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub FillListBox()
    If Len(TextBox1.Text) > 0 Then
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select * from data where name like '" & TextBox1.Text & "%' ", Con)
        Dim rdr As OleDbDataReader
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        cmd.Dispose()
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        If rdr.HasRows Then
            While rdr.Read
                ListBox1.Items.Add(rdr("name"))
            End While
        End If
        rdr.Close()
    Else
        ListBox1.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select * from data where name like '" & ListBox1.Text & "' ", Con)
    Dim rdr As OleDbDataReader
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    cmd.Dispose()
    If rdr.HasRows Then
        While rdr.Read
            TextBox2.Text = CStr(rdr("info"))
        End While
    End If
    rdr.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    dbLoad()
    FillListBox()
End Sub
End Class
```

I appreciate that if anybody can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't open your connection in the Form.Load. The user could start your program and then go to lunch. There sits your connection chewing up database resources. I know it is a bit more typing but define your connection where you use it and open it just before you execute your command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only shows the one record because you are overwriting the textbox on each iteration:

```
If rdr.HasRows Then
    Dim builder as New System.Text.StringBuilder("")
     While rdr.Read
         builder.AppendLine(CStr(rdr("info")))
     End While
     TextBox2.Text = builder.ToString()
 End If
```

Use a StringBuilder to get all your content and display it at once.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I want to show them **separately** by clicking on each of them, **not at once**.

Comment: Dear @Ctznkane525, Please if you know how to show them separately by clicking on each items and not at once, help me. Knowledge is the only treasure that increases with use and consumption.  Thanks!